# Eazfuscator. An error occurs when using the DataGridView control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, eazfuscator

my code is as follows:

```
IList<Users> myData = new List<Users>();

myData = HelperUsers.GetUsersList(); // return IList<Users>

BindingSource bsUsers = new BindingSource { DataSource = myData };
dataGridViewUsers.DataSource = bsUsers;

dataGridViewUsers.Columns["Name"].HeaderText = "Name";
dataGridViewUsers.Columns["LastName"].HeaderText = "Last name";

dataGridViewUsers.Invalidate();
```

works perfectly still in debug, but when compiling as releace occurs following error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in the line:

```
dataGridViewUsers.Columns["Name"].HeaderText = "Name";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Name property of your Users class is being renamed/obfuscated. Therefore the Columns collection doesn't have an entry for it.

Per the Eazfuscator you can do the following to disable class property renaming:

```
[System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute(Feature = "properties renaming")]
class MyOneThousandAndThirdClass {
    // ...
}
```

Or for a single property:

```
class MyOneThousandAndFourthClass {

    [System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute(Feature = "renaming")]
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Comment: ok,  but if I comment the lines which set up the columns. be continued without data on the grid

Comment: @andres - You would need to exclude those properties from obfuscation. You can generally do this by making the type and properties public. If that's not what you want, most obfuscation tools allow you explicitly select which properties to exclude from obfuscation.

Comment: @andres - Updated with info from documentation.